# Using Bash Scripting to save output in an csv file

Tags: bash

I prepared a .sh file that runs a C program and print the result in an external file. Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

min=-2
max=2

(echo $min; echo $max) | CFiles/main > main_data.csv
```

The only problem is that I don`t want the sentences "Enter the minimum value"  and "Enter the maximum value" to be printed in the csv file. I only want the data generated by the program after it receives the input values. What should I do?

The source of main is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "c_operations.h"

int main(void) {

  INT i, j, out;
  const VALUE min, max;
  COMPLEX z;
  PLANE a;

  printf("Enter the minimum value: ");
  scanf("%Lf", &min);
  printf("\n");
  printf("Enter the maximum value: ");
  scanf("%Lf", &max);
  printf("\n");

  a = constructor(min, max);

  for(i=0; i<100; i++){
    for(j=0; j<100; j++){
      z = get(&a, i, j);
      out = iterate(z, 0);
      printf("%Lf, %Lf, %ld\n", z.x, z.y, out);
    }
  }

  delete_plane(a);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add source of `main` to your question.

Comment: I would just rewrite the C program to accept arguments, only prompting for input if they're missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best answer, take @miken32's suggestion.

Otherwise, just add a filter to remove the first 2 lines of the output:

```
{ echo $min; echo $max; } | CFiles/main | sed '1,2d' > main_data.csv
```